# Unable to read excel data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Hi I am trying to work with excel files in visual studio. Trying to read them, however getting an error. Want help in this regards.

```
const urlStatusCode = require("url-status-code");
const xls = require("xlsx");

const url = 'https://www.cricinfo.com'
let workbook = xls.readFile("sitemap.xlsx");

let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

for(let ind = 0; ind < 390000; ind++){
    let urll = worksheet[`A${ind}`].v;
    console.log(urll);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
    let urll = worksheet[`A${ind}`].v;
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'v')
```

If I remove .v I do get results but I have t: , h: ,v: and all. Please guide me anyway out. Looking forward.

Comment: What prints out if you remove the `.v` ?

Comment: just do `let worksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames[0]]);`

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, this is not the v, t or h, it is worksheet[`A${ind}`] which is undefined. Try debugger and check & resolve the value of it.